# Confusion over args for Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am a little confused over the arguments needed for Puppeteer, in particular when the `puppeteer-extra` `stealth` plugin is used. I am currently just using all the default settings and Chromium however I keep seeing examples like this:

```
let options = {
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-sync',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    ],
    defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 }
};
```

Do I actually need any of these to avoid being detected? Been using Puppeteer without setting any of them and it passes the bot test out of the box. What is `--no-sandbox` for?

Comment: `--no-sandbox`: "Disables the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed. Meant to be used as a browser-level switch for testing purposes only. "

Comment: `--disable-sync`: "Disables syncing browser data to a Google Account"

Comment: @kavigun so I shouldn't need `--no-sandbox` right? I'm not testing anything. Just running puppeteer

Comment: @Kex I would advise you to use it if only the headless browser can't be started (on some linux systems). It may introduce a huge security risk using that flag against pages that you don't trust. and I don't think you don't need it for [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) to work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are chromium features - not puppeteer specific

please take a look at the following sections for `--no-sandbox` for example.
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox

> **Setting Up Chrome Linux Sandbox**
> In order to protect the host
> environment from untrusted web content, Chrome uses multiple layers of
> sandboxing. For this to work properly, the host should be configured
> first. If there's no good sandbox for Chrome to use, it will crash
> with the error No usable sandbox!.
>
> If you absolutely trust the content you open in Chrome, you can launch
> Chrome with the --no-sandbox argument:
>
> ```
> const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox',
> '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
> ```
>
> NOTE: Running without a sandbox is
> strongly discouraged. Consider configuring a sandbox instead.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/sandboxing.md#linux-sandboxing

> Chromium uses a multiprocess model, which allows to give different
> privileges and restrictions to different parts of the browser. For
> instance, we want renderers to run with a limited set of privileges
> since they process untrusted input and are likely to be compromised.
> Renderers will use an IPC mechanism to request access to resource from
> a more privileged (browser process). You can find more about this
> general design here.
>
> We use different sandboxing techniques on Linux and Chrome OS, in
> combination, to achieve a good level of sandboxing. You can see which
> sandboxes are currently engaged by looking at chrome://sandbox
> (renderer processes) and chrome://gpu (gpu process).\
>
> . . .
>
> You can disable all sandboxing (for
> testing) with --no-sandbox.